# Multiple One-to-Many Relationships to the Same Entity

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization, database-relations

I have a system that takes `orders`, and an order can have one or many `files`. The file belongs to one order.

[image]

Also, `orders` can have one or many `revisions`. For these revisions, it used to be that they can upload 0 or 1 files. So I had a `one-to-zero-or-one` relationship going on.

[image]

Now it turns out that they can upload 0 or many files for a revision. I am unsure of how this would typically be handled. The only idea I can think of is the moment is adding a `revisions_id` to the `files` table and allowing it to be nullable. With this, the `order_id` will always be required, to know which order it's for, and if there is a `revisions_id`, I'll know it's from a revision and will be able to join them together.

[image]

As usual, I know cases are situational. But I was wondering if this is an approach that would be deemed acceptable by other developers that have run into this issue before.

Comment: Perhaps you should get rid of the link between `files` and `orders`, thereby forcing queries to go through a `revision`.  Consider the "original" version is a "revision".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, it is possible to have data where `revisions_id` and `orders_id` relationship is not maintained in the `files` table.

An alternative approach can be to remove the relationship between `orders` and `files` and have the relationship between `files` and `revisions`. Every order being inserted in the `orders` table will need to have an initial revision record inserted in the `revisions` table.

Comment: Could you possibly explain the first part more, where the relationship wouldn't need to be maintained in the `files` table?

Comment: You can derive the relationship between `files` and `orders` through `revisions` table. Since every record in the `orders` table will have a corresponding record in the `revisions` table (the initial record with `revisions.id = 0` or similar), you will be able to map every file to an order.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not sure that would work for my case. Sorry I left out some of the finer details. But just to stay on this path for a moment, the `files` table would then just have a `revisions_id` column then, correct?

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for the response. I'm just not positive if I'd want to create a revision record every time a file is uploaded. Basically, our order system is used by the internal team, as well as our customers. Our internal team can make changes and upload files as needed, but the revisions are created whenever the customers makes a change, so we know that someone on the internal team needs to take a look and work on it.

So those are the finer details. I'll think about your suggestion some more, and see if I can come up with something, unless someone else is able to chime in.